# combine multiple spacy textcat_multilabel models into a single textcat_multilabel model

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy, spacy-3

**Problem:** I have millions of records that need to be transformed using a bunch of spacy textcat_multilabel models.

```py
// sudo code 

for model in models:
    nlp = spacy.load(model)
    for groups_of_records in records: // millions of records
        new_data = nlp.pipe(groups_of_records) // data is getting processed bulk
        // process data 
        bulk_create_records(new_data)
```

My current loop is as follows:

1. load a model
2. loop through records / transform data using model / save

As you can imagine, the more records i process, and the more models i include, the longer this entire process will take. The idea is to make a single model, and just process my data once, instead of `(n * num_of_models)`

**Question:** is there a way to combine multiple textcat_multilabel models created from the same spacy config, into a single textcat_multilabel model?

Comment: I have all training sets. each model is trained with a single category bool

Answer (score 1):

There is no basic feature to just combine models, but there are a couple of ways you can do this.

One is to source all your components into the same pipeline. This is very easy to do, see the [double NER project](https://github.com/explosion/projects/tree/v3/tutorials/ner_double) for an example. The disadvantage is that this might not save you much processing time, since separately trained models will still have their own tok2vec layers.

You could combine your training data and train one big model. But if your models are actually separate that would almost certainly cause a reduction in accuracy.

If speed is the primary concern, you could train each of your textcats separately while freezing your tok2vec. That would result in decreased accuracy, though maybe not too bad, and it would allow you to then combine the textcat models in the same pipeline while removing a bunch of tok2vec processing. (This is probably the method I've listed with the best balance of implementation complexity, speed advantage, and accuracy sacrificed.)

One thing that I don't think has been tested is that you could try training separate textcat models at the same time with separate sets of labels by manually specifying the labels to each component in their configs. I am not completely sure that would work but you could try it.

Comment: Couldn't i just use the tok2vec (roberta-base) to save my vectors, then just send vectors to the models to get predictions? As long as I use the same (roberta-base) transformer while building the models, i shouldn't have to pre-process my data before running it through the N models?

Comment: I guess im confused as to why the accuracy would go down if i handle the pre-processing externally.

Comment: By default the transformer is fine-tuned when training, which should improve accuracy. But if you fine-tune it with one model that model won't work with the others. So you have to give up on fine-tuning to share the transformer with multiple classifiers.